# Self Referencing Object (Field is result of another) Jinja

Tags: ansible, jinja2, templating

Hello Guys and Girls :D

I'm trying to create an object in which a field depends of another, imagine in the group_vars/all file is something like:

```
people_names:
 - first_name: tom
   last_name: hardy
   full_name: " {{ first_name}} {{ last_name}} "
```

The task is very simple just (I'm trying to debug this)

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: Test jinja2template
    template: src=test.j2 dest=test.conf
```

And the *test.j2* would be something like:

```
{% for person in people_names %}
person_full_name = person.full_name
{% endfor %}
```

Is this even possible in Ansible/Jinja with ?

To build this I'm running the command:

```
ansible-playbook jinja2test.yml --check --diff --connection=local
```

If you need any more info please do not hesitate to ask and thanks in advance :D

EDIT:
When i run this I get *AnsibleUndefinedVariable* for the *last_name*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Create an object in which a field depends on another."*

A: It's not possible. See for example [#8603](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/8603#issuecomment-260745851). Create the dictionary with full names if you need it. For example

```
  vars:
    people_names:
      - first_name: tom
        last_name: hardy
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        people_full_names: "{{ people_full_names|default([]) +
                               [item|combine({'full_name': full_name})] }}"
      loop: "{{ people_names }}"
      vars:
        full_name: "{{item.first_name}} {{ item.last_name }}"

    - debug:
        var: people_full_names
```

gives

```
    "people_full_names": [
        {
            "first_name": "tom", 
            "full_name": "tom hardy", 
            "last_name": "hardy"
        }
    ]
```