Ansible evaluate jinja expressions in dictionary
Using the template module you can evaluate Jinja expressions in a file, and using the template action plugin you can do the same.
But if you have a dictionary (or string) containing some Jinja statements in the values, is it possible to evaluate these in the same way as a template (or in other words, a template that has not been persisted to disk)?
Example:
- name: Define the dictionary with Jinja expressions
  set_fact:
    my_dict:
      greeting: "Hello, {{ ansible_facts['os_family'] }}!"
      farewell: "Goodbye, {{ ansible_facts['os_family'] }}!"
- name: show templating results
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.template', my_dict) }}"

In this example, if my_dict had been written out to a file, the template module would evaluate the Jinja expressions, whereas right now template expects a filename.

Yes you can evaluate Jinja inside a dictionary but you cannot evaluate a property of the same dictionary, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60826820/2123530. This said, as it stands, your question is quite vague, you might want to be more focused in your question and bring an actual example of what you are trying to achieve.

There is also the option to use YAML anchors, as answered there https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369237/2123530
